# Stylelint Unknown word for interpolation syntax in SCSS

Tags: css, sass, stylelint

I am getting an unknown word error for the follow SCSS:

```
$tags: p, hr, pre, blockquote, ol, ul, menu, li, dl, dt, dd, figure, figcaption, search, main;

@each $tag in $tags {
  #{$tag} {
    @include apply-strong-styles(#{$tag});
  }
}
```

The error displays as:

```
Unknown word (CssSyntaxError)Stylelint(CssSyntaxError)

<#{$tag}>
Selector Specificity: (0, 0, 1)
```

I am getting the same error for `$property` in:

```
@mixin important-styles($styles, $important: false) {
  @each $property, $value in $styles {
    #{$property}: $value #{if($important, "!important", "")};
  }
}
```

I have researched the Stylelint documentation but not found a way to fix this issue. There was a bug in post-css that I am using, however this is marked as fixed.

Please help with a solution.

**References:**

- [Unknown word" error in SCSS syntax and interpolated value with function #36](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-scss/issues/36)
- ["Unknown word" error for interpolated value with function #1640](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/1640)
- [Stylelint Unknown word Errors & warnings](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/errors#unknown-word)

Answer (score 0):

The "Unknown word (CssSyntaxError)" error is likely thrown by the default parser in Stylelint, which can't parse SCSS interpolation like `#{$tag}`.

When linting something other than vanilla CSS, [you should](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/get-started#linting-css-like-languages-and-css-within-containers) use the [`customSyntax` option](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/options#customsyntax) or extend a community config that does that for you:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I already have extends 

{
    "extends": ["stylelint-config-standard-scss"], 
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": ["WebExtension/**/*.scss"],
        "customSyntax": "postcss-scss"
      }
    ]